# How to link two different physics objects together?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a winter hat model which has cloth simulation on it. The model : 
[image]
This is not the final model but this should give you the dea

Is there any way to make the fur parts heavier than the cloth part? I modeled the hat parts separately. I tried parenting the cloth part to the fur parts of the cap while keeping two different simulations on them.

Thanks

Comment: Cloth stiffness scaling?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Is there a way to make the cloth more stiff in one area and leave the rest of the cloth less stiff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to make the cloth more stiff in one area and leave the rest of the cloth less stiff, is to create a vertex group, and assign desired scale of each vertex in this group (0.0 .. 1.0). It's better to do it with weight painting mode. Then you just set this group as stiffness scale factor map. See pictures below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Anywhere you see those vertex group selector, you can do it on per-vertex basis.